# Cannot display products by tag

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list, tags

How to display the products which have a tag? When I go to the page `/tag/product/list/tagId/3/` the page is empty (but the sidebar is shown). I enabled template path hints but there doesn't seem that the product list block is called. How to display the products?

[image]

Comment: Footer is displayed also?

Comment: Yes. All is displayed well except the product list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem once. Check in the Admin → System → Configuration → Advanced → Advanced if the `Mage_Tag` module is enabled. If not enable it. It should work.

Comment: Whoa, thanks man. Now the page is shown. I remembered why I disabled it (I installed a tag cloud plugin).